# App crashes without error logs when using React Native background upload lib on Android 12 and 13

Tags: android, react-native, debugging, android-gradle-plugin

I have encountered a critical issue while trying to upload an image from my Android phone using the React Native background upload library. Despite extensive troubleshooting, I have been unable to determine the cause of the problem. Here are the details:

**Problem**: Whenever I attempt to upload an image, my app crashes abruptly without generating any error logs or stack traces. I have even tried using the

```
"adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V"
```

command to view the logs, but no error or other information is showing.

*The same code works perfectly fine on Android 10 and 11, but the app crashes consistently when using Android 12 and 13.*

```
   try {
      await Upload.startUpload({
        ...options,
        ...{maxRetries: 1, timeout: 100000},
      })
        .then(async uploadId => {
          console.log(
            `Upload started with options: ${JSON.stringify(options)}`,
          );
          this.setState({uploadId, progress: 0});
          Upload.addListener('progress', uploadId, data => {
            this.handleProgress(+data.progress);
            console.log(`Progress: ${data.progress}%`);
            if (data.progress == 100) {
              console.log('this.uploader', this.uploader);
            }
          });
          Upload.addListener('error', uploadId, data => {
            console.log(`Error: ${data.error}%`);
            this.props.feedSavingFailuire(data.error);
            Upload.cancelUpload(uploadId);
          });
          Upload.addListener('completed', uploadId, data => {
            if (
              this.state.initialResponseId != JSON.parse(data.responseBody).id
            ) {
              this.setState({
                initialResponseId: JSON.parse(data.responseBody).id,
              });
              this.props.uploadingCompleted(JSON.parse(data.responseBody));
            } else {
              this.props.uploadingCompleted(JSON.parse(data.responseBody));
            }
          });
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log('Upload error!', err);
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('err', err);
      alert(err);
    }
```

**Update:**

I have identified the cause of the crash after some debugging. Before the crash, I am receiving this exception message

*To target S+ (version 31 and above), it is necessary to specify either FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE when creating a PendingIntent. It is highly recommended to use FLAG_IMMUTABLE. Use FLAG_MUTABLE only if the PendingIntent needs to be mutable for specific functionality, such as inline replies or bubbles.*

I have attempted various solutions found on the internet, but none of them resolved the issue.